# Ruby method chaining with blocks - confusingly inconsistent syntax error

Tags: ruby, syntax, block, method-chaining

So, thinking I'm all clever, I add a method like this to `Object`:

```
class Object
  def apply_if(cond)
    if cond
      yield self
    else
      return self
    end
  end
end
```

This (I thought) allows my to conditionally add bits to a method chain, which simplifies my ActiveRecord query manipulation quite a bit. But it gives a syntax error, which I can reduce down to the following code:

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5]
results = data.
  apply_if(true and false) do |q|
    q + [0,0]
  end
```

Likewise this errors:

```
results = data.apply_if(true and false){|q| q + [0,0]}
```

But this works:

```
results = data.apply_if ((true and false)) {|q| q + [0,0]}
```

As does:

```
results = data.apply_if (true && false) {|q| q + [0,0]}
```

I see that the differences there are all to do with operator precendence, but how can the precedence of an operator *inside a pair of parentheses* matter?

Why is there a syntax error here at all? I don't see any likely syntactic ambiguities, and this method is identical in shape to the Array#reduce method.

I've tried a number of combinations here - explicit block parameters with calls, various types of explicit precedence inside the method definition. Using a lambda instead of a block worked fine, but is obviously too clunky to use for my purposes.

Comment: Dude, Eric. Didn't I teach you better? That code is desperately crying out for a ternary operator! :)

Comment: I originally (and may again) wrote it to also accept a proc in the condition position (one that takes the object as its parameter), which seemed cleanest as a 3-branch conditional. I use ternaries, I do!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with any of your code — the `and` operator just isn't allowed in an argument list. As for *why*, you'd have to ask the Core team, but the most obvious possibility IMO is that its raison d'etre (having extremely low precedence) doesn't work in an argument list.

Comment: I wonder how I've never run into that restriction before? Seems to be the only problem, thanks :-)

Comment: I found [a thread at ruby-core](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-core/7553) about this topic. See  [matz comment](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-core/7559) and an [answer](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-core/7560) on it.

Comment: @knut: Thanks for that. Got to love when your wild guesses are actually right.

Comment: I still haven't adapted to thinking of comma as an operator.. This makes sense now though; thanks for the discussion link!